# Bootstrap alerts autohide doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I've found the great post about making alerts in mvc project. I have implemented it from here: http://jameschambers.com/2014/06/day-14-bootstrap-alerts-and-mvc-framework-tempdata/
There is an _Alert partial view

```
@{
    var alerts = TempData.ContainsKey(Alert.TempDataKey)
                ? (List<Alert>)TempData[Alert.TempDataKey]
                : new List<Alert>();
    if (alerts.Any())
    {
    <hr />
    }
    foreach (var alert in alerts)
    {
        var dismissableClass = alert.Dismissable? "alert-dismissable" :  null;
        <div class="alert alert-@alert.AlertStyle fade in @dismissableClass">
            @if (alert.Dismissable)
            {
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            }
            @Html.Raw(alert.Message)
        </div>
    }
}
```

After I wanted to add autohide function to the alerts. So, I've added a script to this view:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".alert").hide();
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work, so why?

Answer (score 1):

document.ready fires in full page-load, not in partial page-load. hence, the `$(document).ready` event will not fire after the load of this partial view and not execute the code.

write the setTimeout code after the partial view's html.

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".alert").hide();
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: It work's only if I add this script in to the layout or somewhere to the full-page.